# My bar graph in C has good outputs except for one case

Tags: c

I was supposed to write a bar graph in C which draws a bar graph on the screen based on the entered sequence of numbers, using the characters | (vertical line), * (asterisk) and - (minus).
The program first allows you to enter a sequence of a maximum of 20 elements in the interval [-10,10]. The input is interrupted when the user enters the value 999. If the user enters a value outside the interval [-10,10] that is not 999, it is necessary to print the message "The number is not in the requested interval" and stop the program. After completing the input, vertical columns composed of as many characters as | are drawn what is the value of the member of the string, where the sign * (asterisk) is placed instead of the last member of the string. There are two spaces between every two columns. It is necessary to draw a horizontal line that indicates zero. An asterisk should be placed on the horizontal line for members of the array whose value is zero.

My problem is that i have a good output except for one case.

since some words are not in english:
matrica  matrix,
visina  height,
sirina  width,
imaasterisk  has asterisk.

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int niz[20], i, j, k, brojac = 0, visina = 0, sirina = 0, max = 0, min = 0;
  char matrica[50][50];
  int imaasteriks[50] = {0};

  printf("Unesite clanove niza: \n");

  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &niz[i]);

    if (niz[i] == 999)
    {
      break;
    }

    else if (niz[i] > 10 || niz[i] < -10)
    {
      printf("Broj nije u trazenom intervalu");

      return 0;
    }

    brojac++;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 50; j++)
    {
      matrica[i][j] = ' ';
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < brojac; i++)
  {
    if (niz[i] > max)
    {
      max = niz[i];
    }

    if (niz[i] < min)
    {
      min = niz[i];
    }
  }

  visina = 1 + abs(max) + abs(min);
  sirina = 2 * brojac + brojac;

  for (k = 0; k < brojac; k++)
  {
    for (j = 3 * k; j < 3 * k + 3; j++)
    {
      for (i = 0; i < visina; i++)
      {
        if (i == max)
        {
          if (niz[k] == 0 && imaasteriks[k] == 0)
          {
            matrica[i][j] = '*';
            imaasteriks[k] = 1;
          }

          else if (j == 3 * k)
          {
            matrica[i][j] = '-';
          }

          else
          {
            matrica[i][j] = '-';
          }
        }

        else if (niz[k] > 0)
        {
          if (j == k * 3 && i == max - niz[k])
          {
            matrica[i][j] = '*';
          }

          else if (i > max - niz[k] && j == 3 * k && i < max)
          {
            matrica[i][j] = '|';
          }

          else
          {
            matrica[i][j] = ' ';
          }
        }

        else if (niz[k] < 0)
        {
          if (i == max - niz[k] && j == k * 3)
          {
            matrica[i][j] = '*';
          }

          else if (i < max - niz[k] && i > max && j == k * 3)
          {
            matrica[i][j] = '|';
          }

          else
          {
            matrica[i][j] = ' ';
          }
        }

        else if (j != k * 3 && i != max)
        {
          matrica[i][j] = ' ';
        }
      }
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < visina; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < sirina; j++)
    {
      printf("%c", matrica[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

```
INPUT: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10

MY OUTPUT:
           *                                               
            |  *                                            
            |  |  *                                         
            |  |  |  *                                      
            |  |  |  |  *                                   
            |  |  |  |  |  *                                
          --------------------*-----------------------------
----------                       *  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  
 |  |  |                            *  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  
 |  |  |                               *  |  |  |  |  |  |  
 |  |  |                                  *  |  |  |  |  |  
 |  |  |                                     *  |  |  |  |  
 |  |  |                                        *  |  |  |  
 |  |  |                                           *  |  |  
 *  |  |                                              *  |  
    *  |                                                 *  


DESIRED OUTPUT:

*                                                                  
|  *                                                               
|  |  *                                                            
|  |  |  *                                                         
|  |  |  |  *                                                      
|  |  |  |  |  *                                                   
|  |  |  |  |  |  *                                                
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  *                                             
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  *                                          
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  *                                       
------------------------------*-----------------------------       
                                 *  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |         
                                    *  |  |  |  |  |  |  |         
                                       *  |  |  |  |  |  |         
                                          *  |  |  |  |  |         
                                             *  |  |  |  |         
                                                *  |  |  |         
                                                   *  |  |         
                                                      *  |         
                                                         *
```

Comment: You are accessing arrays out of bounds. https://godbolt.org/z/9cWWEefEs

Comment: Don't use *magic numbers* in your code (except where absolutely required like with the `scanf` *field-width* modifier). Instead, If you need a constant, `#define` one (or more), or use a global `enum` to do the same thing. That way you have one single place at the top of your code to change things if needed and you don't have to go picking through your declarations or loop limits to change things. E.g. `#define ROWS 50` and `#define COLS 60` and `#define NIZ 20` and update all references in your code.

Comment: Additionally, you cannot use any of the `scanf()` family of functions correctly unless you ***Check The Return!!***. E.g., `if (scanf ("%d", &niz[i]) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid integer value entered.\n", stderr); break; }` (to discard and continue looping you need to extract the characters causing the *matching-failure* from `stdin` before continuing -- lest you enter the dreaded *infinite-input-loop*) Try it! Enter `"foo"` as a value and see just how fragile your input routine is.... (have `Ctrl+c` ready)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @retired-ninja said you are accessing an array out of bounds. The easiest way to fix it is to change:
`char matrica[50][50];` to `char matrica[50][60];`

But it is better to use defines for those numbers. And if you want numbers from -10 to 10 you also need your array size to be 21, not 20. `int niz[21]`
and

```c
for(i=0;i<21;i++){
    scanf("%d", &niz[i]);
```

So you could do something like

```c
#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 21
char matrica[2*MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][3*MAX_ARRAY_SIZE]; 
int niz[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE]
```

and also use that constant everywhere in your code.

Comment: If there is a *"... maximum of 20 elements ..."*, how do you come up with `int niz[21]`?? (suspect you confused a range-count with the max number of elements...)

Comment: Well depends what the op wants. If he wants a range from -10 .. 10 the maximum number of elements needs to be 21.

Comment: Agreed, but I read it as max of 20 elements that can be anywhere in the range from -10 to 10, not that the values have to be contiguous between them. But, it will be up to the OP to clarify. However, using 21 as the number of elements and compiling/running the code produces output similar to what the OP is trying to avoid...

Comment: Hm with the second piece of code I posted I see a correct bar graph. I also agree, the wording in the question means max is 20. Just the example input from -10 .. 10 with all numbers inbetween made me believe OP is not aware of the fact that you need an array of size 21 to cover numbers between -10 .. 10.  But you knows, maybe he is aware and he really wants max 20. I will update my answer in case I get some more feedback.